# Trouble with Flake8 and atom

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8, linter

I am trying to use Linter with atom, on some python files and I keep getting this error. 
[Console Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPEZH.png). I am not sure what to do here, Python is on the PATH and so is flake8.

Can anyone provide clarification here?
Also I am using Python 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Let speak a bit about your environment. Unfortunately, I can't suggest what *exactly* you need to do as you provided very little information. Nevertheless, your question contains enough information for a generic answer.

The `flake8` tool could be in your PATH in terminal (whatever you use), but not in PATH of the `Atom` editor. You could achieve your goal by one of the following actions or a combination of them.

1. Modifying global PATH, like user PATH in Windows Environment variables, or /etc/paths in macOS (I have no information if ~/.profile would work)
2. Trying to run tool directly by full path (for example, `/opt/local/Library/…` or `C:\Python37\…`)
3. Use script-wrapper, which will set required variables and enables Virtual Environment if needed.

Comment: Flake8.exe is included on the global PATH. I am running a windows 10 64-bit system. However, the issue seems to be that atom, does not recognize that flake8 is available or installed.

Comment: according to log you provided, Flake8 tries different environment or python in first place.This happens often if you have a few Python versions installed.

Comment: Did you installed Python in `c:\`? if so, please, reinstall it to a different directory. This also could be an issue